# Modal is opening but the value from Inputs is undefined. It happens just with the first opening of modal

Tags: html, angular, modal-dialog, frontend

Hello I have a kind of confirmation modal with Inputs :

```
 @Input('input1') input1: string;
 @Input('input2') input2: boolean;

 constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
 }

 ngOnInit() {
 }

 public openModal(): void {
     console.log(this.input2)
     console.log(this.input1)
     this.confirmationModal.nativeElement.classList.add('open-modal');
 }
```

The parent Component when I'm opening this modal inside a subscribe method. In this method I'm assigning the values like this:

```
@ViewChild('confirmationModal') confirmationModal;
input1: string;
input2: boolean;
ngOnInit(): void {    
}

ngOnDestroy(): void {
}

close(project: any) {  
 this.service.close(project).subscribe((success: ModelDto) => {
            this.confirmationModal.openModal();
            this.input2 = success.input2;
            console.log(this.input2)
            this.input1 = 'Some text';
        });
    }
```

In html I have :

```
<app-confirmation-modal #confirmationModal
                        [input1]="input1"
                        (sendConfirm)="toggleSettled($event)"
                        (generateReport)="generateReport()"
                        [input2]="input2">
</app-confirmation-modal>
```

Here is a method openModal from my confirmationModal:

The two presented `console.logs` give undefined only on first opening of the modal.
So when I first try to open the modal I got an empty modal and input1 and input2 are undefined. But From this point every time I open a modal I got values that should be there both in modal and in `console.logs`. So the problem is only with the first opening and I have no clue what can cause it.

Edit:
I've tested it for more time and it appears that it's like 1 click delayed. I mean the values presented in Modal are from a cycle before than values that should be in actual click

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I know what's going on here. *ngOnInit* is too early, the child views haven't been initialized yet. Try *ngAfterViewInit* instead. See Component life-cycle Hooks from the Angular2 docs for more details.

From the docs:

*ngAfterViewinit*: After Angular creates the component's view(s).

Comment: Actually I'm not having it in ngOnInit :) I already tried every life-cycle Hook I know and there was always a problem with the first opening of modal

Answer (score 0):

You might have to trigger change detection manually. Try the following

confirmation-modal.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Output, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class ConfirmationModalComponent  {
  .
  .
  constructor(private _cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  public openModal(): void {
    this._cdr.detectChanges();
    console.log(this.input1)
    console.log(this.input2)
    this.confirmationModal.nativeElement.classList.add('open-modal');
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show how `input1` and `input2` are defined?

Comment: I mean the parent component. And please post it in the question. There is no code formatting in comment.

Comment: 1. Assign values to input variables before calling `this.confirmationModal.openModal();` 2. I don't think adding a CSS class is the best way to open a modal. See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ng-bootstrap-modal-content?file=app%2Fmodal-content.ts

Comment: 1. Actually I tried to assign values vefore calling as well, the result is always the same. First opening of modal gives me 2 undefined. Next ones are good. And in regard to 2 I'm not using bootstrap module and the rest of modals in whole project are done that way, so I think it can't be the problem

Comment: Then I am out of options. I don't really get why they're undefined at first.